# Select position inside Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wonder if there is any plugin that lets me do this:

- Click on the map, and auto generate the latitude and longitude. I have seen one somewhere, but don't know what library the site is using.
- Click on the map, generate closest address. This I haven't seen before.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position with a simple click listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
          alert(e.latlng);
        });
```

To get the closest address take a look at reverse Geocoding.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Edit: all of this is included in the basic google maps api :)